# Is it possible to get the DOM structure of a page after all JS executes?

Tags: javascript, dom, curl, google-chrome-devtools, onload

It's pretty straightforward to use something like cURL or (in PHP) stream contexts/`file_get_contents` to get the starting HTML markup of a page, but nowadays, with so many pages being heavily controlled by JS, even if you get the starting markup for a page, you still cannot readily determine what the actual makeup of the page is (because so much of the page is made up by JS running client-side).

As such, is it possible to get the entire DOM structure of a page after all on-load JS for the page executes by using something like cURL, etc.?

(As a extra bit of info, I know that you can get the DOM structure with Chrome dev tools, etc., but I'm wondering if there's any way to automate the process.)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to run it in a browser, then get the contents of `document.documentElement.outerHTML`.

I don't think this is possible in PHP alone. You'll have to use:

- [phanthomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

  > PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. 
  >   Access and manipulate webpages with the standard DOM API, or with usual libraries like jQuery.
- or [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/).

  > SlimerJS is similar to PhantomJs, except that it runs Gecko, the browser engine of Mozilla Firefox, instead of Webkit.